# Does vue-router works with inline-templates?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to render multiple components that use inline-templates  using vue-router but as soon as i define the inline-template the component renders no matter the url.

Does inline-templatesworks with vue-router?

Comment: Yes, they do. However, there's no code here, so we cannot help you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question lacks any information that could be used to determine the root source of the problem.

Comment: Might want to checkout the documentation first, before asking, there are even examples in the Github repository.

Comment: @Anuga could you share me a link from the vuejs.org documentation? 

As far as i know the documentation don't talk about using vue-router and inline-templates

Comment: no `inline-template` in the docs

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on what you mean by "work". You can Frankenstein something like this and it will do what you want without throwing any errors, but I feel I'm making the world an uglier place by just posting this example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Vue-router with inline-template</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <router-link to="/foo">Go to Foo</router-link>
    <router-link to="/bar">Go to Bar</router-link>
    <router-view>
      <foo inline-template id="foo"><div>foo</div></foo>
    </router-view>
  </div>

  <script>
    const Foo = { template: document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML };
    const Bar = { template: '<div>bar</div>' };
    const routes = [
      { path: '/foo', component: Foo },
      { path: '/bar', component: Bar },
    ];
    const router = new VueRouter({
      routes,
    });
    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      router,
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is pretty much the intro example from [vuejs.org](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/) with one of the templates made into inline.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to your inline template using #

```js
const Foo = { template: '#my-foo-template' }

const routes = [
 { path: '/foo', component: Foo },
];
```

```html
<foo inline-template id="my-foo-template"> ... </foo>
```